# Аналог в c# многомерного массива строк из php

Tags: c#, массивы

как в C# в массив string[] добавить значения типа многомерного как в php
типа такого

> $array['klucchslovo'] = "znachenie"; - именно текст

в C# все облазал так и не понял

> public string[] arr = { }; дальше не знаю...

И как потом к этим ключам обращаться

Comment: + как потом к этим ключам обращаться

Comment: Вам нужен не массив, а словарь `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте словарь.

Мини-пример с разными возможностями словаря:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "key1", "value1" },
    { "key2", "value2" },
};

myDict.Add("key3", "value3");

if(myDict.Keys.Contains("key1"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("key1 is present in myDict");
    Console.WriteLine($"its value is={myDict["key1"]}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("key1 is NOT present in myDict");
}

Console.WriteLine();

if (myDict.Keys.Contains("key4"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("key4 is present in myDict");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("key4 is NOT present in myDict");
}

Console.WriteLine();

foreach (var element in myDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"key={element.Key},{element.Value}");
}

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine($"Количество элементов {myDict.Count}");
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Словари бывают не только строковые, начните изучение с этого примера, а потом двигайтесь в сторону изучения других вариантов.

Ссылки по теме:

- [MSDN Класс Dictionary.KeyCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/3fcwy8h6(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Коллекция Dictionary](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.9.php)