# Как HashSet сериализовать в json?

Tags: c#, json

Начну с кода:

Записываю все значения в файл таким способом ( всё что есть )

Класс BaseAccount:

```
public class BaseAccount
{
   [JsonProperty("Browser")]
   public string BrowserName { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("Link")]
   public string Url { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("Login")]
   public string User { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("Password")]
   public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

Класс GetPass:

```
private static HashSet<BaseAccount> _Logs = new HashSet<BaseAccount>();
public static void Inizialize()
{
   // большой кусок кода
    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = ComText.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            _Logs.Add(new BaseAccount
             {
               BrowserName = Name,
               Url = reader,
               User = reader,
               Pass = Pass
             });
        }
    }
   // Записываю в файл:
   foreach (BaseAccount ss in _Logs)
   {
       File.AppendAllText("pass.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ss, Formatting.Indented));
   }
}
```

Но на выходе получаю не корректный формат json

```
{
  "Browser": "Opera",
  "Link": "https://account.mail.ru/login/",
  "Login": "MyRecovery",
  "Password": "Test"
}{
  "Browser": "Opera",
  "Link": "https://passport.yandex.ru/restoration/changepassword",
  "Login": "MyRecovery",
  "Password": "Test"
}{
  "Browser": "Opera",
  "Link": "https://e.mail.ru/messages/inbox/",
  "Login": "MyRecovery",
  "Password": "Test"
}
```

Вопрос: Как получить формат данного типа ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{
  "browsers": {
    "chrome": [
      {
        "site": "http:\/\/google.ru",
        "login": "test",
        "password": "test"
      },
      {
        "site": "http:\/\/vk.ru",
        "login": "test",
        "password": "test"
      }
    ],
    "citrio": [
      {
        "site": "http:\/\/google.ru",
        "login": "test",
        "password": "test"
      }
    ],
    "opera": [
      {
        "site": "http:\/\/mail.ru",
        "login": "test",
        "password": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[**Update**]

Добавил класс Wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper
{
  public HashSet<BaseAccount> Browsers { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь в классе GetPass:

```
// За место HashSet был добавлен Dictionary
private static Dictionary<string, BaseAccount> _Logs = new Dictionary<string, BaseAccount>();
public static void Inizialize()
{
  using (var Connect = new SQLiteConnection(...)
  {
     Connect.Open();
     using (var ComText = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, Connect))
     {
       using (var reader = ComText.ExecuteReader())
       {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
              // Но теперь данный метод добавления данных не работает 
              // Ошибка в _Logs.Add           
             _Logs.Add(new BaseAccount
             {
                BrowserName = Name,
                Url = reader,
                User = reader,
                Pass = Pass
             });
          }
       }  
     }
  }
}
```

Ошибка следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому что вы решили в цикле сами обходить элементы и каждый сериализовать отдельно. А вы должны сделать сериализацию только один раз - всего объекта. Не переживайте, json конвертер достаточно умный, чтобы самому обойти все ваши дочерние узлы.

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Logs, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

На выходе:

```
[
  {
    "Browser": "123",
    "Link": "http://ya.ru",
    "Login": "login1",
    "Password": "secret1"
  },
  {
    "Browser": "123",
    "Link": "http://ya.ru",
    "Login": "login2",
    "Password": "secret2"
  }
]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример полностью:

```
void Main()
{
    _Logs.Add(new BaseAccount{
        BrowserName = "123",
        Url = @"http://ya.ru",
        User = "login1",
        Pass = "secret1",
    });
    _Logs.Add(new BaseAccount
    {
        BrowserName = "123",
        Url = @"http://ya.ru",
        User = "login2",
        Pass = "secret2",
    });
    _Logs.Dump();
    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Logs, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    serialized.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

private static HashSet<BaseAccount> _Logs = new HashSet<BaseAccount>();

public class BaseAccount
{
    [JsonProperty("Browser")]
    public string BrowserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Link")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Login")]
    public string User { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Password")]
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

Это основное в чём была ваша ошибка. Также если нужно - можете дополнительный класс сделать:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public HashSet<BaseAccount> Browsers { get; set; }
}
```

Сериализуя его

```
var b = new Wrapper { Browsers = _Logs };
var serialized2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
serialized2.Dump();
```

получите на выходе:

```
{
  "Browsers": [
    {
      "Browser": "123",
      "Link": "http://ya.ru",
      "Login": "login1",
      "Password": "secret1"
    },
    {
      "Browser": "123",
      "Link": "http://ya.ru",
      "Login": "login2",
      "Password": "secret2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Antlion Оу, десериализация подобного json -- это самый ходовой вопрос в теме json :) Я вас отправлю на нашу [классическую закрывашку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987) по этой теме, поменяйте HashSet на Dictionary<string, BaseAccountWithoutBrowserName>

Comment: @Antlion ну поставьте для начала  `Dictionary<string, BaseAccount>` и сразу увидите лишнее поле Browser - вот его потом и уберёте.

Comment: @Antlion Покажите ваш код, не скриншотом, не в комментариях. Можно задать новый вопрос, можно в этот внести update (кнопка "править")

Comment: @Antlion Понятно. Вы не умеете работать с такой структурой как Dictionary, почитайте в букварях по c# или посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/907976/213987). Вам надо добавлять так: `_Logs.Add("chrome", new BaseAccount { ... });` А разницу вы и не поняли и ещё и не увидели: вам не нужно будет поле Browser внутри класса, зачем вам дублирование.

Comment: @Antlion Похоже, что вы не очень хорошо ориентируетесь в языке. Разумеется, я имел ввиду что вместо троеточия вы подставите свои параметры из реального кода - все эти reader'ы и приведения типов.

Comment: @Antlion Во-первых, лучше просто грохнуть это поле у класса - оно дублируется. Во-вторых, создать отдельный класс, я вам даже ему имя дал, но вы тогда это не поняли ;) В-третьих, если ну очень нужно зачем-то (зачем?) оставить - ну впишите null и [навесьте атрибут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10169648/5752652) [JsonIgnore]. Какой из этих трёх способов вам лучше подойдёт -- смотрите сами.

Comment: @A K, Ещё один вопрос касательно этой темы: [Скриншот](https://i.ibb.co/LSW6rnk/image.jpg)